What is free (Baxter) algebra over empty set?
In the article "Baxter Algebras and Hopf Algebras" it is stated that divided power algebra is a free Baxter algebra of weight 0 over the empty set. I don't understand this statement. In 1969 Rota's article "Baxter algebras and combinatorial identities I", introducing the concept of Baxter algebras, a free Baxter algebra is explicitly defined to have a nonempty set of generators. Suppose I ignore this and try to construct a free Baxter algebra over an empty set, using the general definition of a free object. Supposedly this means the following: a free Baxter algebra $F(\varnothing, \lambda)$ of weight $\lambda$ together with a Baxter algebra morphism $i: \varnothing \to F(\varnothing, \lambda)$ is such that for any other Baxter algebra $B(\lambda)$ of weight $\lambda$ and for any Baxter algebra morphism $\varnothing \to B(\lambda)$ there exists a unique B.A.M. $f: F(\varnothing, \lambda) \to B(\lambda)$ such that $\varphi = f \circ i$. How am I supposed to define the Baxter algebra structure on the empty set, to check if the maps from the empty set are Baxter algebra morphisms? Further, suppose this structure is well-defined. The map from an empty set to any other is unique. This makes the diagram for the free Baxter algebra commute by definition for every Baxter algebra morphism $f: F(\varnothing, \lambda) \to B(\lambda)$ and for any pair of Baxter algebras between which the morphisms exist, since both $\varphi$ and $f \circ i$ have $\varnothing$ as domain and $B(\lambda)$ as codomain, and thus coincide.
